# How do you replace text with a link tag when using .hover()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, jquery-hover

I'm trying to make a "contact" section in the navigation bar of a website (with jQuery) that includes `<a>Instagram</a>` and `<a>Email</a>` but that only appears when I hover on `#contact`.

So far I've only been able to make strings appear when I hover over `#contact`.

HTML:

```
<span id="contact">CONNECT</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#contact").hover(function(){
  $(this).text(function(i, text){
    return text === "CONNECT" ? "Instagram | Email" : "CONNECT";
  })
});
```

How could I make I make it so "Instagram" and "Email" are links?

I tried this:

```
$("#contact").hover(function(){
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
        return text === "CONNECT" ? "<a>Instagram</a> | <a>Email</a>" : "CONNECT";
    })
});
```

but when I hovered I got `"<a>Instagram</a>"` and `"<a>Email</a>"` as strings and not links.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.html()` to update if you need to set HTML instead of `.text()`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#contact").hover(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, text) {
      return $(this).text() === "CONNECT" ? "<a>Instagram</a> | <a>Email</a>" : "CONNECT";
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="contact">CONNECT</span>
```

Comment: You achieved the hover thing. But they don't appear as links. I think the user wants them to be clickable as `a` tags.

Comment: Adding the <a> tag makes it clickable and I'm sure the OP knows that to make it a link it needs to be <a href="www.link.com">

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good way to do this is by creating two link elements and append them to the "CONNECT" span like this:

```js
$("#contact").hover(
  function(){
    $( '#contact' ).empty();//Remove everything

    $("<a>", {
    text: 'Instagram',
    title: "Instagram",
    href: "www.instagram.com"
    }).appendTo( '#contact' );

    $("<span>", {
    text: ' | ',
    }).appendTo( '#contact' );

    $("<a>", {
    text: 'Email',
    title: "Email",
    href: "mailto:name@gmail.com"
    }).appendTo( '#contact' );  
},function(){
    $( '#contact' ).empty();//Remove everything
    $( '#contact' ).text("CONNECT");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="contact">CONNECT</span>
```